# ASP.Net Core MVC needs <environmentVariables> in web.config to work

Tags: asp.net-core

I am publishing my ASP.Net Core 3.1 MVC project to IIS. The project includes a web api controller along with mvc controllers. It generates a web.config file as below. Once published, the app shows the page but the web api doesn't work unless I add the < environmentVariables > pointing to Development. If I put Production instead, it doesn't work.

Web.config Generated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\MyApp.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Web.config Modified:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\MyApp.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>   
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Modified portion of web.config

```
<environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
<environmentVariables>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me the details error message about the web api doesn't work? Does it return 404 error or 500 error? Besides, I suggest you could check the startup.cs codes or route codes to make sure you haven't added some  codes like this`if (env.IsDevelopment())` to disable some web api settings.

Comment: This is the error I see in the browser console. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://mysite/api/myapi.
Like I said, the page loads the cshtml content, only the api call fails.

Comment: I checked the startup.cs, nothing specific for env.IsDevelopment(); except this line app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

Comment: I think I have simmilar problem. I use ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development" in **launchSettings.json** and use **web.config without environmentVariables** section. When I start app in IISExpress it starts in Production mode instead of Development. I think it is related to latest VS update, because it worked differently not a long ago. Can anyone confirm my assumptions?

Comment: I think I found the cause of the errors:
https://github.com/dotnet/websdk/issues/564#issuecomment-644714341

Answer (score 1):

Update Visual Studio to v16.6.3, which was just release (June 30). It apparently includes a fix for this issue. I just went through this similar problem, posted here:

[Why do environmentVariables from launchSettings.json profiles not load when aspNetCore web.config sections exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688881/why-do-environmentvariables-from-launchsettings-json-profiles-not-load-when-aspn)