# How to get current application url from launchsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is there a reasonably simple way to retrieve the current application url from launchsettings.json? For example, in development I have localhost:5000 and production is https://mywebsitesurl.com.

I saw that you can use inject HTTP Context services, but if possible I'd like to access its property in the same way you can access AppSettings.Json properties

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688881/why-do-environmentvariables-from-launchsettings-json-profiles-not-load-when-aspn) solve your issue?

Comment: `launchSettings.json` is not part of the build output by default, or even publish output. It is just for debugging purposes. Moreover the `applicationUrl` specified inside the debug profile accepts multiple URLs (delimited by semicolon). So in essence, your website could have been reached via any of those URLs &  just by that setting, you won't be able to find out.
It would be better and trustworthy to retrieve the URL via HttpContext

Answer (score 0):

in appsettings.json add this

```
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Services": {
    "NameofMyurlSite": "http://localhost:1000 or your URL site"
  }
}
```

in startup add this

```
 services.AddHttpClient("NameofMyurlSite", config => {
        config.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["Services:NameofMyurlSite"]);
    });
```

if your need use your site for httpclient or receive data, use `IHttpClientFactory`

```
 var client = _httpClient.CreateClient("NameofMyurlSite");
                var datasBody = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clientDatas), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var response = await client.PostAsync("your-endpoint", datasBody);

example endpoint= https://mywebsitesurl.com/api/datas
```